# Is it possible to make 3 stacks of locations? Stack<>()

Tags: c#, stack

Is it possible to do a stack like this

```
  Stack<Location> labels = new Stack<Location>()
     labels.Push(label1, 400, 100)
     labels.Push(label2, 400, 200)
```

I need to know if this is possible. If it is please tell. Thanks

Comment: Tell me if i need to make this more clear.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Do you think it will increase readability?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, although I wouldn't advice it. Create an extension method and place it into a public static class. The following example assumes that there's a constructor accepting a string and two integers for the class Location.

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static void Push(this Stack<Location> stack, string label, int x, int y)
    {
        stack.Push(new Location(label, x, y));
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't suggest extension methods in general because, while they can be useful in small projects, it may become really difficult to keep track of them in a bigger solution. If not properly documented and/or referenced, they can lead to nasty compilation errors or bugs.

Answer (score 0):

For that matter,
You can also also create a LocationStack class which wraps your `Stack<Location>,` and exposes the friendly method that you are looking for!!